# Windows 8 App Development using Dhtmlxscheduler

Tags: javascript, windows, scheduler, dhtml, indexeddb

I am writing a notification application which based on DHTMLxScheduler.

I would like to know more abut the idea of CRUD by IndexedDB for DHTMLxscheduler

As far I know, the following website shows an excellent example

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594924/Build-Calendar-App-for-Windows-8-with-dhtmlxSchedu

However, the data store is not persistent and the application would freeze during multi-touch event.

Does anyone can help to direct the coding needed for the CRUD by its default IndexedDB using the following?

```
    scheduler.attachEvent("onEventDeleted", 
              function(event_id,event_object){
    //add event to the data store
}); 

scheduler.attachEvent("onEventChanged", function(event_id, event_object){
    //update event in the data store 
}); 


scheduler.attachEvent("onEventAdded", function(event_id, event_object){
    //delete event from the data store 
});
```

The following example shows how to integrate by IndexedDB
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=868

However, they shares different framework, while the original scheduler sample used callback always to detect changes.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDB takes relatively lot of code for CRUD operation, so tutorial has been seriously simplified in order not to overload it with implementation details.
There is also complete example with working CRUD, check the '/samples/CalendarApp/' folder of this package:
http://dhtmlx.com/x/download/regular/dhtmlxScheduler_windows.zip

As for multi-touch issue, most probably it will be fixed in the nearest time. Current version of the package is based on dhtmlxScheduler3.7, we are going to update it to 4.0 which has an improvements for windows based touch devices.

And here is a example of database handling, similary to how it's done in the app from dhtmlx site.

```
//connect to indexedDb and fire the callback on success
function connect(callback){
    try{
        var db = null;

        var req = window.indexedDB.open("SchedulerApp", 1);
        req.onsuccess = function (ev) {
            db = ev.target.result;
            if(callback)//fire a callback on connect
                callback(db);
        }

        req.onupgradeneeded = function(e){
            //The event is fired when connecting to the new database, or on version change.
            //This is the only place for defining database structure(object stores)
            var db = ev.target.result;

            if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains("events")) {
                //create datastore, set 'id' as autoincremental key
                var events = db.createObjectStore("events", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
            }
        }
    }catch(e){
    }
}


//add js object to the database and fire callback on success
function insertEvent(data, callback) {
    connect(function (db) {
        var store = db.transaction("events", "readwrite").objectStore("events");
        var updated = store.add(data);
        updated.onsuccess = function (res) {
            callback(res.target.result);
        }
    });
}


// use all defined above with the dhtmlxScheduler
// when user adds an event into the scheduler - it will be saved to the database
scheduler.attachEvent("onEventAdded", function (id) {
    var ev = copyEvent(scheduler.getEvent(id));//where copyEvent is a helper function for deep copying
    delete ev.id;//real id will be assigned by the database

    insertEvent(ev, function (newId) {
        scheduler.changeEventId(id, newId);//update event id in the app
    });
    return true;
});
```

However, I can't guarantee it will work right away, I can't test the code at the moment.
I'd also suggest you to check these articles on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj154908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

FYI, I work for DHTMLX